# git cannot squash commits

Tags: git, rebase

I cannot squash commits with `git rebase -i command`, getting the following error message.

```
error: could not apply 3ad5c7b... 

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
```

What is the error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Is there some conflicts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fix merge conflicts in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git)

Comment: @PRC type `git status` and show us the output, what does it say?

Answer (score 6):

Git failed to merge automatically. Try `git mergetool` and resolve conflicts, then continue your rebase with `git rebase --continue`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have used a `git rebase` before and didn't completed it. To verify it, type `__git_ps1` and verify if the word rebase appear. To resolve this, you need to abort the earlier rebase with `git rebase --abort` and the apply the rebase you want.

Comment: When you typed `__git_ps1`, what did you get?